# How do I create a new db entry and populate the foreign key based on autocomplete selection of that foreign key object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a ASP.NET MVC application i am developing, and have a repair model that includes a foreign key to a serial number model. In my view i have a typeahead jquery doing a autocomplete search through database to allow the user to select a serial number already in the database. I then have fields to fill out new information that will populate the repair table. I cannot seem to get the selected SerialNumber.Id to populate in the Repair.SerialNumber_Id from the selected serial number.

my view:

```
@model EntityTestApp.Models.Repair

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Repair</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RepairDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RepairDate, new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RepairDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SerialNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <input id="serialNumberTextBox" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SerialNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerComplaint, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CustomerComplaint, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerComplaint, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IssueFound, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.IssueFound, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueFound, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RepairActionTaken, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.RepairActionTaken, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RepairActionTaken, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section scripts{
<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {


        var SerialNumbers = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Number'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: '/api/serialnumbers?query=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });

        $('#serialNumberTextBox').typeahead({

            highlight: true
        }, {
            name: 'SerialNumbers',
            display: 'Number',
            source: SerialNumbers
        }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, SerialNumber) {

            //alert(serialNumberTextBox.value)

        });

    });


    </script>    
}
```

my Controller action to create a new repair entry:

```
// GET: Repairs/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Repairs/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public ActionResult Create(Repair repair)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Repairs.Add(repair);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(repair);
        }
```

And my repair model:

```
public class Repair
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime RepairDate { get; set; }
    public SerialNumber SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public string CustomerComplaint { get; set; }
    public string IssueFound { get; set; }
    public string RepairActionTaken { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, several hair pulling nights later i figured it out. I had to add a hidden field to hold the value for the foreign key and assign that value based on the 'typeahead' javascript autocomplete selection with "document.getElementById('').

Works like a charm. Thanks for the help!

-Chris